# Why is PDOStatement->columnCount not returning the right number?

Tags: php, pdo

I'm querying the database first to get all records associated with a certain userid, then i need to go in and modify the array, because one of the fields is an id and i need the name associated with that id.

So i use columnCount to iterate through the resulting array at the index of the id and replace it with the right name, which works fine, for the first six results. columnCount only returns 6, but those first six are renamed as they should be. But outside of that it takes the results from that pdostatement and populates the table normally, with all the relevant data, 17 rows right now.

Why is it returning 6, or what am i doing to get that wrong columncount?

```
global $__CMS_CONN__;
    $timeqry = 'SELECT facility_id, program, date, visit_length, mileage, served FROM timesheet_db WHERE volunteer_id = '.$_SESSION['user_id'];
    $stmt = $__CMS_CONN__->prepare($timeqry);
    $stmt->execute();
    $columns = $stmt->columnCount();
    print $columns;
    if($stmt)
    {
        $arrValues = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        for($x=0;$x<$stmt->columnCount();$x++)
        {
            global $__CMS_CONN__;
            $qry = 'SELECT facility FROM facility_db WHERE id = '.$arrValues[$x]['facility_id'];
            $stmt1 = $__CMS_CONN__->prepare($qry);
            $stmt1->execute();
            if($stmt1)
            {
                $facilityName = $stmt1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                foreach ($facilityName as $item)
                {
                    foreach ($item as $key => $val)
                    {
                        $arrValues[$x]['facility_id'] = $val;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        print "<table style=\"font-size:90%\">\n";
        print "<tr>\n";
        print "<th style=\"width:100%\">Facility</th>";
        print "<th>Program</th>";
        print "<th>Date</th>";
        print "<th>Visit Length</th>";
        print "<th>Mileage</th>";
        print "<th>Served</th>";
        print "</tr>";
        foreach ($arrValues as $row)
        {
            print "<tr>";
            foreach ($row as $key => $val)
            {
                print "<td>$val</td>";
            }
            print "</tr>\n";
        }
        print "</table>\n";
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked for six columns in your first `SELECT` query:

```
SELECT facility_id, program, date, visit_length, mileage, served FROM timesheet_db WHERE volunteer_id = $_SESSION['user_id']
```

So, naturally, `columnCount()` is 6. It doesn't multiply the column count by the number of rows returned or anything like that.

If you want the number of *rows*, you need `count($arrValues)` (the manual says database behavior with [`rowCount()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) is inconsistent regarding `SELECT`s).

Comment: LOL! Boy do I feel like a tard. I'm trying to get the number of results returned

Comment: @Ryan: That's `rowCount`. But if you are iterating over the rows, why don't just do `foreach ($stmt as $row)`. PDO is awesome, why not use its awesomeness?

Comment: Yeah, I was looking for rowCount, I guess I need some coffee or something. Thanks for waking me up.

Comment: @nikic: I thought of `rowCount()` too but the manual says it may not count the rows selected with `SELECT` and shouldn't be relied on.